# Randomising the colour of an image component

Tags: java, image-processing

Ok so im stuck on a method where i have to return each component in an image but have the colour of each component randomised. This is what i have so far:

```
public Picture colourComponentImage()
{
    Picture picture = new Picture(fileLocation);
    int width = picture.width();
    int height = picture.height();

    // convert to black and white
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
        {
            Color color = picture.get(x, y);
            if (Luminance.lum(color) < threshold)
            {
                picture.set(x, y, Color.BLACK);
            }
            else
            {
                picture.set(x, y, Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
    }

    // union - find data structure
    connected(height, width);
    find(height);
    union(height, width);

    // Randomises the colour of each component

    Random random = new Random();

    float r = random.nextFloat();
    float g = random.nextFloat();
    float b = random.nextFloat();

    Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);
    return picture;
}
```

can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What doesn't work in your current approach?

Comment: the picture won't show up when i run the program and since i can't see the picture i don't know if the colour randomisation is working or not

Comment: do you know how to draw in java? you need a toplevel container (frame) and draw there on its graphics... do you know this and do you do this in your code? if **yes** please submit that code... if **no** plaes study http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/

Comment: Looking at your code, I'm pretty sure the random colour is not working - you create a random colour at the END of the method and then never use it!? From what I can see, you're final image will only be BLACK/WHITE.

Comment: @munyul could possible tell me the code that I'm missing? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure if this is what you were trying to acheive...

```
public Picture colourComponentImage()
{
    Picture picture = new Picture(fileLocation);
    int width = picture.width();
    int height = picture.height();

    // Create two random colours
    Random random = new Random();
    Color randomColourOne = new Color(random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat());
    Color randomColourTwo = new Color(random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat());

    // Convert to two tones of any two random colours
    for ( int x = 0; x < width; x++ ) 
    {
        for ( int y = 0; y < height; y++ ) 
        {
            Color color = picture.get(x, y);
            if ( Luminance.lum(color) < threshold )
            {
                picture.set(x, y, randomColourOne);
            }
            else
            {
                picture.set(x, y, randomColourTwo);
            }
        }
    }

    // union - find data structure
    connected(height, width);
    find(height);
    union(height, width);

    return picture;
}
```